# How to overlay a stem plot over a box plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a vector

```
A=[1 2 3 3 3 4 5]
```

I am able to show its box plot with

```
boxplot(A, 'orientation', 'horizontal')
```

I can also show its distribution with a stem plot like this

```
[nelements, centers] = hist(A);
stem(centers, nelements/numel(A), 'blue');
```

My question is how to combine these two plots into one figure? The figure should have its `y-axis` as probability and `x-axis` as the `A` values.

As for the height of the box plot in the figure, it does not matter.

How may I do this?

Comment: See `help hold`, you may have to manually adjust the axes.

Comment: @DougLipinski I did have tried hold on, but one simply replaces the other. ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hold on` as follows, and be aware that you need to vertically move (using `'position'` again) your `boxplot` to fit the axes of `stem`

```
boxplot(A, 'orientation', 'horizontal','position',0.1); hold on
[nelements, centers] = hist(A);
stem(centers, nelements/numel(A), 'blue'); hold off
```

[image]